# Make a server ( other than the router ) to be the default gateway for a subnet

Tags: networking, gateway, load-balancer

I am trying to make a server ( lets call it server_A) which is different from the router to be the gateway for a subnet. 
Why do I want this ? I want to host a loadbalancer on server_A using LVS-NAT, and I dont want to implement a V-Lan or IP-IP tunneling.

I have modified the routing tables of the remaining servers on the subnet to use server_A as the gateway. I have set server_A to not send ICMP reroute packets. But most traffic from servers in that subnet to outside clients are still being sent through the original gateway, bypassing server_A. Is there any other configuration I need to set in order to achieve my goal ?